# trying to convert sql to linq sql

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, sql-to-linq-conversion

I'm trying to convert this SQL code to linq sql. But I don't understand even with the doc... someone can help me please ?

```
select prcleunique, LibelleProjet, from projet a
where eqcleunique in (select EqCleunique from Compo where uscleunique = '{0}') 
and (a.socleunique in (select socleunique from utilisat where uscleunique = '{0}') or a.socleunique is null) 
and a.archive = 2 order by LibelleProjet", idUtilisateur);
```

Comment: Perhaps my [SQL to LINQ Recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245160/sql-to-linq-with-multiple-join-count-and-left-join/49245786#49245786) could guide you.

Answer (score 0):

Those nested sql queries can be broken down nicely in Linq. Every time you have a select have a seperate linq query:

```
var clause1 = from row in _db.Compo where uscleunique == '{0}' select EqCleunique;
```

Then use the clauses in the last query

```
var result = from row in _db.project where clause1.Contains(row.eqcleunique) select row.whatever;
```

I hope this example is enough to get you started.